# PHP/MySQL: Query inserts the GLOBAL username instead of current logged in username

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

### Summary

I have a PHP script that is making a query to my DB and everything is inserted correctly except my current logged in users username. I end up with my DB global username instead.

The username is being passed around as a session **$_SESSION['username']** and I am able to **echo** the correct name, and **print_r($_SESSION)** shows all the correct values.

### notes.php

```
<?php

session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);

// if user is not logged in
if (!$_SESSION['username']) {
  header('Location: home.php');
}

// when user creates new note
if ($_POST['create_note']) {
  include('includes/functions/func_sanitize.php');

  $username  = $_SESSION['username'];
  $note_name = validate_form_data($_POST['note_name']);

  // connect to db
  include('includes/connection.php');

  // make query to db and return the results
  $query = "INSERT INTO `notes` (`id`, `username`, `note_name`, `note_content`, `date_created`) VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$note_name', '', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

  // close db connection
  if ($result) {
    mysqli_close($conn);
  } else {
    mysqli_close($conn);
    echo 'Error: '.$query.'<br>'.mysqli_error($conn);
  }
}

include('includes/header.php'); 

?>

<div class="notes-container container-fluid pt-4">
  <div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-12">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="saved-notes col-10 offset-1 col-md-4 offset-md-0">
          <header class="text-center">
            <h2><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h2>
          </header>
          <div class="pt-2">
            <form action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" class="form-inline px-1" method="POST">
              <input class="form-control mb-1 mr-1" name="note_name" type="text">
              <input name="create_note" type="submit">
            </form>

          </div>
        </div><!-- col -->

        <div class="current-note col-10 offset-1 col-md-8 offset-md-0">
          <header class="text-center">
            <h2>Current Note</h2>
          </header>
          <form action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
            <textarea name="note_content"></textarea>
            <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="note_submit" type="submit" value="Save">
          </form>
        </div><!-- col -->
      </div><!-- row -->

    </div><!-- col -->
  </div><!-- row -->

<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

You can see at the top of the script that I check if the user is logged in with **if (!$_SESSION['username'])** and this is working correctly and like I said before **echoing** the **$_SESSION['username']** also works.

Comment: Where is the Global username found?

Comment: My money is on that in `includes/connection.php` your database username variable is `$username`. Which is overwriting your expected one.

Comment: Was thinking the same. TS should move the includes above the page.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for this, must be a common problem for newer users for you both to diagnose this so quickly.

Comment: You should wrap your headers in exit, else code is executed after, which will cause empty rows to be added, if `create_note` is set, regardless of whether the user is signed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

I was including my **connection.php** further down in the script and it was overwriting my **$username = $_SESSION['username']** variable. Moving the **include('includes/connection.php')** further up the script solved my problem.